# Export flux (Influxdb 2.0) database into csv in CLI

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-python, influxdb-2, influx-line-protocol

I found that we can send a CSV file into Influxdb 2.0, but is the reverse operation possible? How can I export flux database into CSV file in CLI?